# how to get filename without extension using xp_dirtree

Tags: sql-server

I have used `xp_dirtree` to get list of filenames from remote server path folder. the files are with extensions `.bak` I do not want the get the filename with extension `.bak`

for eg:

```
filename Sales_backup_2016_10_09_213002_7679353.bak
```

needs to get

```
Sales_backup_2016_10_09_213002_7679353.
```

I did search many blags for this but no luck.

please can anyone suggest me how to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: You could also just strip the extension from your current filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USE LEFT function : If you are storing result of `xp_dirtree` in table with column Name as FileName then below script will help you.

```
SELECT LEFT(FileName,LEN(FileName)-3)
FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
select substring('Sales_backup_2016_10_09_213002_7679353.bak',1,charindex('.','Sales_backup_2016_10_09_213002_7679353.bak')-1)
```